# Does reporting webservice url contain the function that helps to export the report to the client version?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs, ssrs-2012

The reporting webservice url contains the webservice url that contains all the information of the Reports which are created in SSRS. As the report has been created on reporting service, i want to export/send that report to my client using the SOAP feature.

```
http://localhost/reportserver_INSTANCE2012/reportservice2005.asmx?wsdl
```

While creating the project under soapUI using the above wsdl, it returns 105 functions like

Function Name

```
CreateBatch()
CancelBatch()
CancelJob()
CreateDataDrivenSubscriptionMethod()
CreateDataSource
CreateFolder
CreateLinkedReport
createModelReport
createReport
createReportHistorySnapshot
createResource
CreateRole
CreateSchedule
CreateSubscription
DeleteItem
DeleteReportHistorySnapshot
DeleteRole
DeleteSchedule
DeleteSubscription
DisableDataSource
EnableDataSource
ExecuteBatch
FindItems
FireEvent
FlushCache
GenerateModel
GetCacheOptions
GetDataDrivenSubscriptionProperties 
GetDataSourceContents
GetExecutionOptions
GetExtensionSettings
GetItemDataSourcePrompts
GetItemDataSources
GetItemType
GetModelDefinition
GetModelItemPermissions
GetModelItemPolicies
GetPermissions
GetPolicies
GetProperties
GetRenderResource 
GetReportDefinition
GetReportHistoryLimit
GetReportHistoryOptions
GetReportLink
GetReportParameters
GetResourceContents
GetRoleProperties
GetRoleProperties
GetScheduleProperties
GetSubscriptionProperties
GetSystemPermissions
GetSystemPolicies
GetSystemProperties
GetUserModel
InheritModelItemParentSecurity
InheritParentSecurity
ListChildren
ListDependentItems
ListEvents
ListExtensions
ListJobs
ListModelDrillthroughReports
ListModelItemChildren
ListModelPerspectives
ListReportHistory
ListRoles
ListScheduledReports
ListSchedules
ListSecureMethods
ListSubscriptions
ListSubscriptionsUsingDataSource 
ListTasks
Logoff
LogonUser
MoveItem
PauseSchedule
PrepareQuery
RegenerateModel
RemoveAllModelItemPolicies
ResumeSchedule
SetCacheOptions 
SetDataDrivenSubscriptionProperties 
SetDataSourceContents
SetExecutionOptions
SetItemDataSources
SetModelDefinition
SetModelDrillthroughReports
SetModelItemPolicies
SetPolicies
SetProperties
SetReportDefinition
SetReportHistoryLimit
SetReportHistoryOptions
SetReportLink
SetReportParameters
SetResourceContents
SetRoleProperties
SetScheduleProperties
SetSubscriptionProperties
SetSystemPolicies
SetSystemProperties
UpdateReportExecutionSnapshot 
ValidateExtensionSettings
```

I would like some one to help me out which function is used to send the existing report of SSRS reporting to my client. I am using the wsdl feature to connect directly to the report server and want to use function listed on above, to send the report in any format like pdf etc.

Answer (score -2):

follow the given instruction, and should be able to print the report in format passed format:

https://surendragurjar.wordpress.com/2015/07/11/ssrs-wsdl-web-service-endpoint-using-java/

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers: they are useless when the link disappears.

Comment: In broader: please include here the steps/elements of the solution that helps the OP.  You might have the idea later to move your page to somewhere else - in this case the link will 'rot', making this answer useless.